# NSTableView Right Clicked Row Index

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'm looking for a way to get right-clicked row index from `NSTableView` but I can't find any delegate methods or class attributes for it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I haven't done this, I am pretty sure you can by overriding `NSView`'s `- (NSMenu*)menuForEvent:(NSEvent*)theEvent`.  The example in [this link](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/RightClickSelectInTableView) does a point conversion to determine the index.

```
-(NSMenu*)menuForEvent:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    NSPoint mousePoint = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
   int row = [self rowAtPoint:mousePoint];
   // Produce the menu here or perform an action like selection of the row.
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to find a way without subclassing NSTableView.

Comment: Graham's answer below works without subclassing. Set the NSTableView's menu property to an NSMenu item you own. Set that NSMenu's delegate. In menuNeedsUpdate(_: NSMenu) you can call clickedRow() on the NSTableView. This DOES work for right clicks at the point this menu delegate is called.

Answer (score 23):

Use the [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method `- (NSInteger)clickedRow` to get the index of the last clicked row. The returned NSInteger will be the index of the right clicked row.

You do not need to subclass `NSTableView` for this solution. `clickedRow` is also available on `NSOutlineView`.

Comment: I don't think this should work when right clicking a row because the return value of clickedRow is only meaningful in the target's implementation of the action or double-action method.

Comment: This works, so long as it is called from within the NSTableView's target action or doubleAction method. Do you have another situation where you want the clicked row?

Comment: I think the original poster asked for a solution when right clicking a row.  From what I could tell it's not possible to trigger either of those methods with a right-click.

Comment: According to the 10.5 release notes (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#X10_5Notes): “The key thing to note is that clickedRow and clickedColumn will now both be valid when a contextual menu is popped up. … The clickedRow and clickedColumn properties will still be valid when the action is sent from the NSMenuItem.”. I found that this does work *if* the table’s `menu` outlet is set and if you override `-menuForEvent:` you have to call `super`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the easiest answer to implement.

Comment: This answer works correctly. Set the NSTableView's menu property to an NSMenu item you own. Set that NSMenu's delegate. In menuNeedsUpdate(_: NSMenu) you can call clickedRow() on the NSTableView. This DOES work for right clicks at the point this menu delegate is called.

Comment: @MichaelTsai that comment is the key for me. I had to use the `menu` outlet. Just creating and returning a `NSMenu()` in code was not updating my `clickedRow` value

Answer (score 7):

### Updated Answer

If you want to get clicked row index on menu opening, the answer is `NSTableView.clickedRow`. Anyway this property is available only in specific moments, and usually just `-1`.

When is this index to be available? That's in `NSMenuDelegate.menuWillOpen` method. So you conform the delegate and implement the method on your class, and access the `clickedRow` property. It's done.

```
final class FileNavigatorViewController: NSViewController, NSMenuDelegate {
    let ov = NSOutlineView() // Assumed you setup this properly.
    let ctxm = NSMenu()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ov.menu = ctxm
        ctxm.delegate = self
    }
    func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        print(outlineView.clickedRow)
    }
}
```

Clicked row index is available until you click an item in the menu. So this also works.

```
final class FileNavigatorViewController: NSViewController {
    let ov = NSOutlineView() // Assumed you setup this properly.
    let ctxm = NSMenu()
    let item1 = NSMenuItem()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ov.menu = ctxm
        ov.addItem(item1)
        ov.target = self
        ov.action = #selector(onClickItem1(_:))
    }
    @objc
    func onClickItem1(_: NSObject?) {
        print(outlineView.clickedRow)
    }
}
```

I tested this on macOS Sierra (10.12.5).

---

### Old Answer

Starting from OS X 10.11, Apple finally added a method to access `clickedRow` easily. Just subclass `NSTableView` and override this method and you'll get the `clickedRow` as far as I experienced.

```
func willOpenMenu(menu: NSMenu, withEvent event: NSEvent)
```

This needs subclassing, but anyway, the cleanest and simplest way to access `clickedRow`.

Also, there's a pairing method.

```
func didCloseMenu(menu: NSMenu, withEvent event: NSEvent?)
```

Comment: Would be awesome if you could provide a working example. I spent the last two days getting a context menu in a NSTableCellView work but failed 

Answer (score 3):

Just select row on right-click by implementing `menuForEvent:` in `NSTableView` subclass:

```
@implementation MyTableView

- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    int row = [self rowAtPoint:[self convertPoint:theEvent.locationInWindow fromView:nil]];
    if (row == -1) 
        return nil;
    if (row != self.selectedRow)
        [self selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row] byExtendingSelection:NO];
    return self.menu;
}

@end
```

Comment: This does not match the behavior in Finder and Mail, which let you use the contextual menu to act on a row without affecting the selection.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont need to open NSMenu but need to know "right click action with row number", i think most simple way is below. (Swift4 Code)  Don't need any other connected Outer NSMenu class.

```
class SomeViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
  ...

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    tableView.action = #selector(some method()) // left single click action
    tableView.doubleAction = #selector(someMethod()) // left double click action
  }

  // right click action
  override func rightMouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let point = tableView.convert(theEvent.locationInWindow, from: nil)
    let row = tableView.row(at: point)
    print("right click")
    print(row)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question but I also needed a solution that would work with multiple selected rows (because when multiple rows are selected and you right-click on one of them, NSTableView highlights all of them). Here's the property I added for this in a subclass of NSTableView:

```swift
var rightClickRowIndexes: IndexSet {
    if clickedRow >= 0 {
        return selectedRowIndexes.contains(clickedRow) ? selectedRowIndexes : IndexSet(integer: clickedRow)
    } else {
        return IndexSet()
    }
}
```

[image]