# NSMenu Not connecting method of another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nsbutton

```
   -(void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent  
{  
    cvcont = [[CollectionViweItemSubClass alloc] init ];  
    NSMenu * m = [[NSMenu alloc] init];  
    //[cvcont openInFinder];----perfectly working------  
    [self setTarget:cvcont];  
    [m addItemWithTitle:@"show in finder" action:@selector(openInFinder) keyEquivalent:@""];// not working-----  
    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:m withEvent:theEvent forView:self];  
}
```

i subclassed the button and calling a method from the class   `CollectionViweItemSubClass` . if i calling as usually it is working. But the method was not connected via `NSMenu`. 
The below code is my method from the class CollectionViewItemSubClass

```
-(void)openInFinder {
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"filePath"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:savedValue inFileViewerRootedAtPath:nil];
```

}

Comment: So are `rightMouseDown` and `openInFinder` in the same class?

Comment: And are you able to *fire* `openInFinder` via the main menu for example?  I'm trying to determine if there is a problem with the class that encloses that method.

Comment: yeah its working when executing `[cvcont openInFinder];`

Comment: No, I mean via a menu, not directly like that.

Comment: no, via menu the method was not fired. the menu text was disabled.

Comment: OK get it working from the Main Menu first and then worry about the pop-up menu later.  The object probably isn't in the responder chain or something.

Comment: got it.. [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185645/context-menu-based-on-nstableviewcell)