# View based NSTableView: how to get the clicked row index?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

When right clicking on a cell view in a view based table view with an assigned menu the cell's row gets a blue outline and the context menu appears. How do I get the index of that row? The property `clickedRow` only works for cell based table views.

Note: my question is significantly different in that I need a solution for menu updates es explained previously:

I need the clicked row in the menuNeedsUpdate function when creating the new menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTableView Right Clicked Row Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494489/nstableview-right-clicked-row-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `clickedRow` indeed also works for view based table views, but it's not yet set in `menuNeedsUpdate`. So it cannot be used to adjust the items in the menu (e.g. show specific items only that apply to the clicked row). However, you can use the menu validation to enable/disable entries (there the clicked row value is set finally).